# Setup django/python with Jenkins

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, jenkins

I currently configure Jenkins for my python/django application (i'm using python 3.5)

During the setup I open a Virtualenv and I activate it.

```
virtualenv -q wecover_platform . 
./wecover_platform/bin/activate
```

Then i install all my requirements from my file requirement.txt

```
pip install -r $WORKSPACE/requirements.txt
```

I can't pass this step i always have a permission denied issue.

```
Installing collected packages: asn1crypto, pycparser, cffi, idna, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, olefile, pillow, reportlab, selenium, django-jenkins
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/asn1crypto'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

If somebody could help me I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Jenkins is trying to install packages, It might need root privileges to do so. Try doing sudo pip install -r  $WORKSPACE/requirements.txt

Comment: i try edit, but i don't understand how did you create virtual env, and the error looks like you don't successful activate the virtualenv

Comment: @PrakashPalnati OP try to install to the virtualenv use sudo is not good idea

Comment: It's weird because the creation of the virtualenv seems to be successfull

Comment: I solve the issue thanks guys :)